# WiFi ICON is gray on my kitkat ONLY at home and ONLY with a specific device

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, networking

I have noticed that when I'm at home, the WiFi icon is always gray, so I cab still have access to the internet but notifications from apps like whatsapp, Facebook, etc doesn't, work. When I connect to another WiFi network like the one on my job, the icon turns to blue and notifications work as expected.

I think the problem may be on my internet at home, but how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
There are some strange things i noticed: It's only this specific phone that does not receive push notifications. I tested with my brother's phone and with one of mi friend and they both receive push notifications... so the problem happens ONLY at home and ONLY with this specific device.

Comment: As Huey stated it is a synch issue. When your device connected the internet and communicate with GMS (Google service) wifi symbol change color. Make sure your sync settings are enabled if you want to get notifications.

Comment: As i said, I AM receiving notifications, just not at home.

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have great service in that area.

Comment: Yeah i thought so, but how can i trace it? There must be an address that is being blocked in my home... what is the google notification service address?

Comment: Anyway, this is not true, because i tested with other devices and they work fine.